# Build a tile server using MySQL as backend

Tags: mapnik, osm2pgsql, tile-server, mysql-spatial

I need to set up a tile server using MySQL but cannot find any documentation for it.

I have done it with Postgres by following this [link](https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/)  and it works fine. 
I understand that after downloading the data from planet OSM I need to use osm2pgsql to store the data in Postgres. Is there any similar tool for MySQL?

Also, would Osmosis, Mapnik and Mod_tile work with MySQL?

I absolutely cannot use Postgres. Is there a step to step guide for MySQL?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/66273/build-a-tile-server-using-mysql-as-backen) to the answer.